OpenSSL Encryption (c++) EVP_DecryptFinal_ex detects different padding to applied EVP_EncryptFinal_ex padding
My C++ program which implements OpenSSL Encryption and Decryption has an inconsistency relating to the padding when I attempt to decrypt an encrypted file.
The encryption function is shown below. This uses EVP_aes_256_cbc() for encryption, with a pass key generated from PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC,using SHA1.
const int Cipher::cIterations = 1000;
const int Cipher::cPassSizeBytes = 48;
const int Cipher::cOk = 1;

int Cipher::Encrypt(const string &plainText,
                    const string &passPhrase,
                    string &cipherText)
{
    const int cKeySizeBytes = 32;
    const int cSaltSizeBytes = 32;
    const int cIvSizeBytes = 32;
    try
    {
        string key(cKeySizeBytes, 0);
        string salt(cSaltSizeBytes, 0);
        string iv(cIvSizeBytes, 0);
        string password(cPassSizeBytes, 0);
        string encryptedStr(cipherText.size(), 0);
        int actual_size = 0;
        int final_size;

        createRandString(salt);
        createRandString(iv);

        rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, cIterations, key);

    
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);

        if(cOk != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx,
                                     EVP_aes_256_cbc(),
                                     NULL,
                                     reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&key[0]),
                                     reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&iv[0])))
        {
            handleErrors();
        }

        if(cOk != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx,
                                    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&encryptedStr[0]),
                                    &actual_size,
                                    reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&plainText[0]),
                                    plainText.size()))
        {
            handleErrors();
        }

        if(cOk != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx,
                                      reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&encryptedStr[actual_size]),
                                      &final_size))
        {
            handleErrors();
        }

        actual_size += final_size;

        encryptedStr.resize(actual_size);

        cipherText = salt + iv + encryptedStr;

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return cipherText.length();
}

And the decryption function is shown below. This uses EVP_aes_256_cbc() for decryption, with a pass key generated from PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC, using SHA1.
int Cipher::Decrypt(const string &cipherText,
                    const string &passPhrase,
                    string &plainText)
{
    const int cKeySizeBytes = 32;
    const int cSaltSizeBytes = 32;
    const int cIvSizeBytes = 32;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    int actual_size = 0;
    int final_size = 0;
    string key(cKeySizeBytes, 0);
    string salt = cipherText.substr(0, cKeySizeBytes);
    string iv = cipherText.substr(cKeySizeBytes, cIvSizeBytes);

    try
    {
        rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, salt, cIterations, key);
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
        // Enc is 1 to encrypt, 0 to decrypt, or -1 (see documentation).

        if(cOk != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx,
                                     EVP_aes_256_cbc(),
                                     NULL,
                                     reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&key[0]),
                                     reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&iv[0])))
        {
            handleErrors();
        }

        if(cOk != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx,
                                    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&plainText[0]),
                                    &actual_size,
                                    reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&cipherText[cKeySizeBytes + cIvSizeBytes]),
                                    cipherText.size()- (cKeySizeBytes + cIvSizeBytes)))
        {
            handleErrors();
        }

        if(cOk != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&plainText[actual_size]), &final_size))
        {
            handleErrors();
        }

        actual_size += final_size;

        plainText.resize(actual_size);

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);

    }
    catch (std::runtime_error &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return plainText.length();
}

void Cipher::rfc2898DeriveBytes(const string &passphrase,
                                const string &salt,
                                unsigned int iterations,
                                string &data)
{

    try
    {
        PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC(passphrase.c_str(),
                          passphrase.size(),
                          reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(&salt[0]),
                          salt.size(),
                          iterations,
                          EVP_sha1(),
                          data.size(),
                          reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&data[0]));
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error &ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cipher::rfc2898DeriveBytes" << std::endl;
    }
}

During encryption, when I call EVP_EncryptFinal_ex, the final_size value is 16, and when I call EVP_DecryptFinal_ex, the final_size value is 10. This doesn't cause a problem in my C++ program but I have problems sometimes when trying to decrypt files not encrypted by my C++ program. I thought that this would be a good place to start investigating.
In this example the encrypted data is encoded to base64 and written to file. When decrypting, the base64 data is decoded prior to calling the Decrypt function. I am confident that this is working and so have excluded this from the code extracts.
During encryption, the generated cipherText array comprises of a 656 bytes, i.e. salt(32) + iv(32) + encryptedStr = 592(576 (actual size) + 16(final_size)).
Whereas when encrypting, the decrypted string is 586 (576 (actual size) + 10(final_size)). Does this mean that the decrypt function removes the padding?
Can anyone help please?

...I have problems sometimes when trying to decrypt files not encrypted by my C++ program... How can the question be answered without information about how these ciphertexts were generated? Presumably a different algorithm, a different key derivation function etc. was used. You have to provide the encryption code or describe the logic used in detail.

The IV for AES is 16 bytes (not 32), OpenSSL removes the padding during decryption (if padding is enabled, which is the default).
